# Selecting all mouse cursor types (one by one)

Tags: c#, wpf, cursor

I'm developing a WPF application in C# and I want to know if is there any way to test all mouse cursor types.
For changing the type of cursor I do this:

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Cross;
```

I built a timer like bellow:

```
 DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
 dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300);
 dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
 dt.Start();
```

Here is my problem:

```
Cursor c = Cursors.AppStarting;
void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Mouse.OverrideCursor = c++; //this doesn't work. 
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
int current = 0;
PropertyInfo[] cursors;
void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(cursors == null)
        cursors = typeof(Cursors).GetProperties();
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = 
        (Cursor)cursors[(current++) % cursors.Length].GetValue(null, 
                                                               new object[] { });
}
```